# unable to access object in an object using index (in typescript)

Tags: typescript, api

This is the error I am getting:

```
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.
```

I am trying to call API/ get request and unable to use id as it is showing.

please describe what I am doing wrong. (I have written this code in javascript and it is working good)

```
type TodoSchema = {
      id: string;
      date: Date;
      title: string;
      completed: boolean;
    };

class Task {
    id: string;
    date: Date;
    title: string;
    completed: boolean;
  constructor(title: string, completed: boolean) {
    this.id = uniqid();
    this.date = new Date();
    this.title = title;
    this.completed = completed;
  }
}



  const taskList= {};

router.get("/todo/:id", (ctx: any) => {
  // list by id
  console.log("Got request =>", {
    method: ctx.request.method,
    path: ctx.request.url,
    body: ctx.request.body,
  });
  const id: string = ctx.params.id;

  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(taskList, id)) {
    goodResponse(ctx, "application/json", taskList[id]); // in this line error
  } else {
    badResponse(ctx, "text/html", "task dosent exists");
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you try reproduce the issue in a minimal example? in this for example, I can't see where taskList comes from.

Comment: Seconded. What is `taskList`? I assume you've done `const taskList = {}` somewhere, when it should be `const taskList = {} as Record<string, Task>`.

Comment: yes i am using const taskList= {};

Comment: using          const taskList = {} as Record<string, Task>      have removed the error

Comment: @samthecodingman it is working now, thanks for the help. can you please share some materials/websites/documentation from where I can learn these things

Comment: I'll put something together later tonight after work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cutting to the point, you have an object called `taskList`, that you want to use as a map of task IDs to their task, but you have defined its type as `{}` (the default empty object type). This object doesn't have an index signature saying that a given ID string may return a `Task` object. You can achieve this using:

```
const taskList = {} as { [taskId: string]: Task };
// or
const taskList = {} as Record<string, Task>;
```

**Note:** `List` implies an array, but this is an object. You should consider using `Map`, `Record`, or `Dictionary` instead. Personally, I normally use `taskMap`. However be careful when you make use of actual [`Map` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) because they use `get()`/`set()` methods (so you can use more than `string | number | symbol` as their key type).

---

But how did we find out about that problem? Let's break down the error message.

First, what is an index signature? An index signature is a special instruction to TypeScript that defines the type of a property on an object when you access a property dynamically. If you had an object called `someObject` an you wanted to get a property's value dynamically, you would use something like `someObject[prop]` where `prop` could have the type of a `string`, `number` or `symbol`.

If you have an ordinary object, like `{}`, its type will be `{}`. Similarly if you have an ordinary object with a defined property, like `{ userId: "someId" }`, it will have a type of `{ userId: string }`. Both of these types do not have an index signature. If you tried to run the following code, you will get the same error you experienced in modern TypeScript:

```
const someObject = { userId: "someId" };
const prop: string = "userId";

const uid = someObject[prop]; // error
```

In older versions of TypeScript, `uid` would simply be given the type of `any` (a special don't-bother-type-checking type) which often led to bugs. Now this pattern throws an error telling you to add the index signature to the object.

To tell TypeScript what the returned type of `someObject[someString]` is, you add an index signature where you specify the type of the property name (conventionally the `key`, although can be renamed) and the type it returns:

```
// define someObject as an object with string properties that return a string
const someObject: { [key: string]: string } = { userId: "someId" };
const prop: string = "userId";

const uid = someObject[prop]; // uid is now treated as a string
```

Importantly here, `uid` **is treated as if** it is a `string`. If you used `const prop: string = "somethingElse"`, TypeScript would still think that `uid` is a string, even though it will be `undefined` when executed as JavaScript. We could tweak the index signature to reflect this:

```
// define someObject as an object with string properties that return a string
const someObject: { [key: string]: string | undefined } = { userId: "someId" };
const prop: string = "userId";

const uid = someObject[prop]; // uid is now treated as a string | undefined
```

Because of how common this particular "dictionary pattern" or key-value map is, where you have a key of a certain type that returns a value of a certain type, you can use the in-built `Record` utility type.

```
const someObject: { [key: string]: string } = { /* ... */ }
```

could be written as

```
const someObject: Record<string, string> = { /* ... */ }
```

The `Record` utility type is also particularly useful when dealing with keys that have finite number of values. Instead of specifying a index of `[key: string]`, you could set it as `[key in "val1" | "val2" | ...]` or pass it into the first type argument of `Record`:

```
type ProviderDataMap = { 
  google: ProviderData,
  facebook: ProviderData,
  twitter: ProviderData
}
```

or

```
type ProviderId = "google" | "facebook" | "twitter";
type ProviderDataMap = { [providerId in ProviderId]: ProviderData };
```

or

```
type ProviderId = "google" | "facebook" | "twitter";
type ProviderDataMap = Record<ProviderId, ProviderData>;
```

There are many of these [in-built utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) like `NonNullable` (value can't be `null` or `undefined`), `Partial<Type>` (the properties of the given type are now optional), `Pick<Type, Keys>` (return a derivative type based on the original, that only includes the listed keys), and so on.

---

Some great TypeScript resources:

- [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html)
- [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/) (like the Handbook, but arguably more in-depth)
- [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) (see TypeScript's compiled form side-by-side to see what its doing)
- [TypeScript in 100 seconds - Fireship on YouTube](https://youtu.be/zQnBQ4tB3ZA)
- [TypeScript - The Basics - Fireship on YouTube](https://youtu.be/ahCwqrYpIuM)
- [Other TypeScript questions here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5btypescript%5d%20isaccepted%3ayes) (for common mistakes/misunderstandings)